# Digital signatures attached to the file

Tags: java, digital-signature

I need to implement digital signatures to my web app. I followed [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-digital-signature) and [this](https://reflectoring.io/how-to-sign/) example, and have successfully signed and verified given file.

My questions are regarding the flow:

1. I can export the signature, so what should I do with the signature? Save it in the database?
2. If I attach signature to the file using `BouncyCastle` exported file is not readable. Should file with attached signature be readable?
3. Is this the correct flow of digital signature: create the signature with user's certificate, store the signature, create endpoint for signature verification?
4. If 3. is correct, does that mean if the file is sent outside an app, recipient wouldn't know if the file is signed? Should the signature be attached to the file? If yes, is there solution for all types of files (ie. I have found pdf based solutions).

Maybe the question is to broad, but I am open to any material regarding the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can export the signature, so what should I do with the signature?

You have to distinguish between Private Key, Certificate and Signature.
**Private Key:** User's private key, if created in cryptographic device, never comes out of the device.
**Certificate**, in very brief, is a signed Public Key. Certifying Authority (CA) Signed it and Certificate is publicly available.
**Signature** is Signed Content.  In fact, content to be signed is hashed and then this hash is signed, which is called Signature.

> Is this the correct flow of digital signature: create the signature with user's certificate, store the signature, create endpoint for signature verification?

Private key is used to sign content (hash of content). The string produced is called Signature. Certificate (Public key) is used to verify signature.

> is there solution for all types of files (ie. I have found pdf based solutions).

Any content can be signed.  Signing text files like CSV data, XML, Json, etc is used by web applications which accepts data from the users or members.  Example being eReturns, Signed Payment settlement data from banks, Tender Forms, etc.  PDF (and some other formats) supports signing and verifying signature and is format widely used to share document. Documents can display visible signature and hence pdf signatures are most discussed format of the Signatures.
Otherwise, any application can define the signing requirement, users (client application or web browser) follow the required standard of signing and then the application can verify that signature is attached (along with data) as per pre-define format and standard.

> I need to implement digital signatures to my web app.

Modern Browsers may need to use Browser Extensions to access Certificate stored on local machine. ex: Signer.Digital Browser Extension

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have one more question, what should I do with the signature (hashed value)? Is it only for my in app verification (if I am not using pdf signature)?

Comment: I am not able to understand what exactly you want to achieve. Content is first hashed. Then hash is signed to produce Signature.  Private Key is required for Signing. Do you mean licensing by "app verification" ?

Comment: What should I do with the signature? I understand the way it's created and it's verification, but I can't find the flow of the application once the signature is created. Am I supposed to save it in the database? As I understand the signature (for all file types(`byte[]`)) can be verified only within my application, or application having access to public key?

Comment: Yes. The typical flow is, user registers his Certificate (and Public Key) at some portal.  Then in future, for some submission, user would sign the content and app will verify Signature against user's registered public key and then accept the content. The app may also choose to store signature along with the submitted content for future verification.  The same mechanism applies to login using Digital Signature where AuthToken (or UserID) and it's Signature is sent while login. Thus user with valid pvt. key can only login using his smartcard or USB Token.

Comment: I have one last question: the application's backend is only responsible for verifying the signature, since I have the user's public key, and not for actually signing the data? Is the client or some other application (like extension you recommended) responsible for signing? The private key isn't actually sent to the server, so I guess local app or the client which can access the private key should sign the data?

Comment: Yes. Client is responsible for signing. In old days, small local app installed used to sign. Then came JavaApplet or ActiveX running in Internet Explorer. Now, modern browsers uses Browser Extension, which uses local app to access local key storage and sign the data.

Answer (score 0):

A valid digital signature gives a recipient reason to believe that the message was created by a known sender (authentication), that the sender cannot deny having sent the message (non-repudiation), and that the message was not altered in transit (integrity)

More info : http://javaint4bytes.blogspot.com/2018/04/java-signature-certificates.html